# React.Fragment Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, electron, eslint

Even though it's working, Visual Studio Code keep displaying error like the screenshot below. AFAIK, my ESLint doesn't seem understand about `React.Fragment`. It displays error to any `<React.Fragment>` or `<Fragment>` that I have.

How to disable or fix this ?

This is an electron-react project, with typescript. I started this project with

```
electron-forge init my-new-project --template=react-typescript
```

then I updated my `react`, `@types/react`, `@types/react-dom` and `react-dom` package to their latest version, since I need the `<Fragment>` component. Fragment is a new feature introduced by React 16.x.x

Here's my current package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-stylus": "^0.1.1",
    "ionicons": "^4.5.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron": "^5.0.1",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "4.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  }
```

I use VSCode 1.33.1 on Debian machine 64bit, ESLint 1.8.2

error code:

```
JSX element type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.
        Type '(props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.
          Type '(props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<any>'.
            Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
              Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.ts(2605)
```

[image: error in visual studio code]

Additional Note: 
When I import `Fragment` as a separate variable with:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Fragment } from 'react'
```

and then try to call the `<Fragment>` component, It still throwing the same error

Comment: What happens if you `import React, { Fragment } from 'react'`, and just use the `<Fragment>`?

Comment: @lux Still the same error... I don't understand why

Comment: @lux I also added some details

Comment: Don't import Fragment and please try with <React.Fragment> </React.Fragment> or <> </>

Comment: @AlokMali : still same.... <React.Fragment> or <Fragment> both display the same error, in fact, the picture that I use above is <React.Fragment>. Even though I can run the code successfully. Can I disable this warning ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using React in an Electron application. With Babel and Webpack set up in the backend for compilation.

I wrote a post with the stack that I'm currently using and how I solved my syntax highlighting issues.

Note that like I think you mentioned, my application was in fact compiling correctly in Webpack/Babel. It was just Visual Studio Code that was giving issues.

In short, changing the language in VSC from `Javascript` to `Typescript` fixed the highlighting.

Here's my post: https://medium.com/@callback.insanity/using-react-fragments-in-visual-studio-code-2019-d19af4469788